# While read loop in parallel

Tags: bash, while-loop, parallel-processing

I have the following while loop in a bash script however I would like to run these in parallel (an failing) can anyone point me in to the right direction please?

Thanks!

```
while read LINE; do
    RAYID=$(echo "$LINE" | jq -r .rayId)
    LINE="$(echo $LINE | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{13\}\)[[:digit:]]\{6\}/\1/g')"
    args=( -XPUT "localhost:9200/els/logs/$RAYID?pipeline=geoip-els" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$LINE" )
    curl "${args[@]}" > /dev/null 2>&1
done <<< "$ELS_LOGS"
```

Comment: Just add a `&` if you want to run each curl command in the background

Comment: Kudos for using `jq` and an array to store the arguments. I might suggest trying to move more of the processing into `jq` as well, so that you have something like `echo "$ELS_LOGS" | jq '...' | while read -r rayid line; do args=(...); curl ...; done`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

** EDITED

Additionally to what @TomFenech stated which is correct, I want to add that it would be also nice if you add **`wait`** after **`done`**, so the script won't finish its execution, until all tasks are completed.

```
function doSomething(){

        RAYID=$(echo "$1" | jq -r .rayId  ) 
        LINE="$(echo $1 | sed 's/\([[:digit:]]\{13\}\)[[:digit:]]\{6\}/\1/g'  )" 
        args=( -XPUT "localhost:9200/els/logs/$RAYID?pipeline=geoip-els" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "$1"  ) 
        curl "${args[@]}" > /dev/null 2>&1 
}

while read LINE; do
   doSomething $LINE &
done <<< "$ELS_LOGS"
wait
```

Regards!

Comment: When I run the above I think it just tries to run all the lines at any time rather than one after the other as it gives me curl errors. :/

Comment: I have edited my response in order to fix you sync problem. Hope it helps you. I basically wrapped your four lines in a function but I did not test it. So let me know. @MatthewBullock

Comment: This is why I love to hate Bash seems likes the function now ignores line '1' & '2' (JQ rayid and the SED) of the function

Comment: Got It! had to replace $1 with $line. Thanks for the help @matias Barrios

Comment: @MatthewBullock No problem buddy.